# Looking for API - how to view daily google doodle in iframe?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, api

I am using [iChrome new tab](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ichrome-new-tab/iccjgbbjckehppnpajnmplcccjcgbdep?hl=en) and  I have customized the new tab to my preference but I miss **google doodle** that is shown in Chromes default new tab.

Is there any way to **only display the google doodle** in an html iframe element or retrieve it by any other means so that search box and other stuffs are hidden yet I can keep myself updated with today's doodle ?

How I want it is like the following image, so please let me know if there is any doodle API or trick do accomplish the same.

[image: I only want to display the logo so that scroll bars are not needed]

Comment: http://www.google.com/doodles/ shows all the doodles.

Comment: i know. I want to see the today's one in a small iframe without having to scroll in it .

Answer (score 0):

```
/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png
```

Is todays, so obviously the URL/file will be unique for each change. But the XPATH should remain static, so if you use JS as far as I know you can reliably retrieve it.

```
//*[@id="hplogo"]
```